# How to use @dataProvider for fetching values from a Text file?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using Text file as a datasource to do datadriven testing. Is there anyway to use dataProvider to fetch values from a text file? Any help is welcome!!!

Answer (score 0):

`dataProvider` dont help you to read any files. It just helps you to invoke the test multiple times with provided data. You can use anything to read files and just convert it to 2D array so that `dataProvider` can use it

```
@DataProvider(name = "provideData")
public Object[][] provideData() {
     // Read data from text file and convert it to 2D array.
}
```

This might help : [**How to read text file in Java.**](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/)